# Website background image jumping on mobile

Tags: html, css

I know here is a few topic for that question, but I tried everything and did not work. I tried the JS solutions to, but I don't know JS well. I'm just a beginner.

I used my background setting in CSS.

```
body:after {
content:"";
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
z-index:-1;
display:block;
background:url('img/4/bike-2756269_1920.jpg') no-repeat 80% 50%;
background-size:cover;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "jumping"? Could you show us what it currently looks like and what it should look like?

Comment: What is the action that triggers this behavior? Hover? Touch? changing the screen size? or combinations? I can only speculate since the code you provide is incomplete. This might be cause of media query which changes dimensions of the image when hovered.

Comment: Is there a specific reason the background needs to be in an after pseudo element?
You could make the body position fixed too and it would not jump (I'm assuming you are talking about the url bar dissapearing and reappearing.), but that is not an elegant solution.

Comment: I used the after pseudo element because no another method worked well in mobile. That was the only solution to show the background image on mobile. If i fix the body position, than i can't scrolling on mobile. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using the `after` element then you could wrap your entire page in a div:

```
<body>
    <div class="outer">...
```

And then use the following css:

```
    .outer:after {
        content:"";
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        z-index:-1;
        display:block;
        background:url('bike-2756269_1920.jpg') no-repeat 80% 50%;
        background-size:cover;
    }
    .outer{
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

This way you can use scroll and have the background in the `after` pseudo element - which is **Not an elegant solution**, unless you want to use it for some js parallax scrolling or similar.

Comment: The url bar is fixed on the phone, but it does not matter anymore. It works finally and that's the point. Thank you very much. This works best on my website. You saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this meta tag may help you.

```
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: the same as it was :(

Comment: It does not work . as meta tag for viewport does not necessary help image position.

Answer (score 0):

You, obviously, need to add this `CSS` rule to ensure that the `after` pseudo-element is positioned relative to the body.

```
body { position: relative; }
```

hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean about not being able to see it on mobile, but have you tried using `background-attachment: fixed`?

```
body {
   background:url('img/4/bike-2756269_1920.jpg') no-repeat 80% 50%;
   background-size:cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This will "lock" your background image in place and still allow the body element to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to assign the background to the body element itself and then If you want to see the whole image in the background then the code becomes like this:

```
body {
    background:url('img/4/bike-2756269_1920.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: How is this answer different than the one I posted 40 minutes ago?

Comment: @disinfor, when using 'cover' property the image fills the whole screen with retaining its dimensions which means that some parts of the images could be cut out and hid behind the screen edges, while with 100vw 100vh it shows the whole image which might cause a damage to its quality.

Comment: The concern isn't how the image is cropped, just that it was jumping. But it looks like he got a solution.